# Stop output from drools when starting OptaPlanner from a JAR

Tags: optaplanner

How to stop the drools logger when executing OptaPlanner from a compiled JAR?

In the logback.xml file the drools output is commented out and when i run the project directly from Eclipse everything is ok the only output is the one from OptaPlanner (either debug or trace) , but when i compile everything into a JAR and run it from the JAR for some reason i also get the drools output.

Comment: Check the default log level in your logback.xml file. If that's debug or trace, change it to warn or info. If it's not, it means it's probably ignored, see slf4j manual to make sl4j output where it gets its logging config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with turning off the Drools logger through the Java API.

```
Logger droolsLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.drools");
droolsLogger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
```